# Relationship type is not showing in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am working with sugar crm 7.1.1 and I am trying to create a subpanel for a module. When I try to create the subpanel I dont see any relationship in dropdown other than "one to one".

How could I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify how this is related to php and/or programming. Currently, I consider this [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sugar often restricts relationships in Studio that it deems "unwise".  You can force the relationship yourself with the various metadata vardefs; you will need to specify the relationship, the subpanel and the relate field.  As an aside, you should really upgrade from 7.1, it is really not for production use.

Comment: @MartinTawse can you suggest any tutorial for that?

Comment: You will get a few hits if you search for "sugarcrm build relationships with code", many Sugar tutorials are total rubbish though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create subpanel then it should be always `One to many` relation ship
 And for **Campaigns**  it is showing only one relation it is a default .
 IF you want more check Account module.